# Error al importar archivo csv separado punto y coma en R

Tags: r, dplyr

Cuando intento descargar un archivo csv separado por puntos y comas lo hace sin ningún problema pero el resultado final no es el correcto.
El script es:

```
df <- read.csv("https://cdn.produccion.gob.ar/cdn-mineria/Datos-Abiertos-SIACAM/Comercio/expominerales-siacam.csv", 
               sep=";", encoding='latin')
```

y el resultado es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en el archivo, si te fijas cualquier línea:

```
"1994;;;Brasil;1;Bentonita;No metaliferos;Brasil;Bentonita;4875"
```

Cada una de estas está encerrada entre comillas, y el funcionamiento por defecto de `read.csv()` es usar comillas para encerrar columnas, por lo que obviamente la línea completa termina siendo una sola columna. Podrías usar `quote=''` para evitar esto, pero el tema es que te quedarían las comillas en la primer y última columna. Por lo que una solución más certera sería leer el archivo de forma plana, reemplazar commilas, salvarlo en un archivo temporal y luego leerlo con `read.csv()`:

```
tmp_file <- tempfile(pattern = "mineria", tmpdir = tempdir(), fileext = ".csv", encoding = "latin1")

lineas <- readLines("https://cdn.produccion.gob.ar/cdn-mineria/Datos-Abiertos-SIACAM/Comercio/expominerales-siacam.csv")
lineas <- gsub('\"', '', lineas)
writeLines(lineas, tmp_file)

df <- read.csv(tmp_file, sep=";", encoding='latin1')
```

Comment: No toma el encoding, antes si. ¿Por qué podría estar pasando eso?

Comment: Probá agregar `encoding = "latin1"` en  `readLines()`